# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java

en resumidas cuentas yo tengo una serie de variables y metodos que obtienen información de unos JOpane y los guarda por un metodo en un array. Ya intente el codigo sin usar el array y estuvo bien, pero cuando lo intento meter en el array me sale este error, quisiera saber si alguien me puede decir como solucionarlo. Cabe aclarar que estoy llamando los metodos desde un JFrame y los estoy ejecutando con un JButton, no se si tenga algo que ver.
JFrame:

```
    package ejercisioalimentos;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Interfaz extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public Interfaz() {
        initComponents();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(149, 149, 149)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(176, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(124, 124, 124)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(154, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        
    
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        Frutas_y_Verduras PrdtsFyV = new Frutas_y_Verduras("","",0,0);
        PrdtsFyV.CrearElmnt();
        PrdtsFyV.MostrarElmnt();
    }                                        
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Interfaz.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Interfaz.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Interfaz.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Interfaz.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Interfaz().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Clase de los metodos:

```
    package ejercisioalimentos;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Frutas_y_Verduras extends Alimentos{
    int Cntd;
    Frutas_y_Verduras[] PrdtsFyV = new Frutas_y_Verduras[Cntd];
    Frutas_y_Verduras Mostrar = new Frutas_y_Verduras(Clasf, Nombre, Precio, Cant);

    public Frutas_y_Verduras(String Clasf, String Nombre, int Precio, int Cant) {
        super(Clasf, Nombre, Precio, Cant);
        this.Cntd=3;
        PrdtsFyV[0]= new Frutas_y_Verduras("FyV","Manzana",2000,8);
        PrdtsFyV[1]= new Frutas_y_Verduras("FyV","Aguacate",3000,10);
        PrdtsFyV[2]= new Frutas_y_Verduras("FyV","Uva",1500,12);
        PrdtsFyV[3]= new Frutas_y_Verduras("FyV","Tomate",3000,7);
    }
    
    public void CrearElmnt(){
        Cntd=Cntd+1;
        Clasf=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese la clasificación del producto");
        Nombre=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese el nombre del producto");
        Precio=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese el precio del producto"));
        Cant=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese la cantidad del producto"));
        Frutas_y_Verduras Obj = new Frutas_y_Verduras(Clasf, Nombre, Precio, Cant);
        PrdtsFyV[Cntd]=Obj;
    }
    public void MostrarElmnt(){
        Mostrar=PrdtsFyV[Cntd];
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,Clasf + Nombre + Precio + Cant);
        
    }
}
```

Clase "madre" de variables(no creo que importe pero lo pongo para complementar):

```
    package ejercisioalimentos;

public class Alimentos {
    String Clasf;
    String Nombre;
    int Precio;
    int Cant;

    public Alimentos(String Clasf, String Nombre, int Precio, int Cant) {
        this.Clasf = Clasf;
        this.Nombre = Nombre;
        this.Precio = Precio;
        this.Cant = Cant;
    }
}
```

Comment: En la segunda linea de la clase Frutas_y_Verduras tienes `Frutas_y_Verduras[] PrdtsFyV = new Frutas_y_Verduras[Cntd]` pero hasta ese momento Cntd que está arriba no tiene ningún valor. Ese es tu problema

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich Gracias! Eso resolvió ese problema, aunque ahora me aparece el mismo error en otra fila pero creo que es por algo similar, si algo la nueva fila es en la que declaro: PrdtsFyV[0]= new Frutas_y_Verduras("FyV","Manzana",2000,8);

Comment: En tu constructor no puedes crear una instancia de la misma clase . Ese es el stackoverflow. Si en el constructor haces `PrdtsFyV[0]= new Frutas_y_Verduras("FyV","Manzana",2000,8)` estás volviendo a ejecutar el constructor de esa clase y entras en un loop infinitoinito. No será que quieres hacer la la clase Alimentos? Si es así cambia el tipo de tu arreglo

Comment: Perdón Alimentos es la clase base. Debes evaluar nuevamente como has diseñado tu solucion

Comment: En todo caso ese arreglo debe cargarse por fuera de la clase. En la clase que usa Frutas y Verduras.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich De acuerdo, veré como puedo resolverlo.